# How to configure autocomplete for dojo in Notepad++

Tags: dojo, notepad++, intellisense

I want to develop dojo application. For speed coding, I want to use autocompletion in Notepad++ for dojo.

Can anyone please help me on how to enable autocompletion for dojo in Notepad++?

Answer (score 0):

On other **SynWRite** editor: you can create text file with Acp extention, for your lexer (dojo), see Help topic "auto-completion".

In Notepad++ it's harder, needed XML file..